# Bloom filter implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, bloom-filter

This is an implementation of Bloom filter with `add` and `contain` functionality.  I'm looking for code review, best practices, optimizations etc.

I'm also verifying complexity: \$O(1)\$

```
public class BloomFilter<E> {

    private final BitSet bitSet;
    private final int hashFunctionCount;
    private final MessageDigest md5Digest;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty Bloom filter. The optimal number of hash functions (k) is estimated from the total size of
     * the Bloom and the number of expected elements.
     * 
     * @param bitSetSize
     *            defines how many bits should be used in total for the filter.
     * @param expectedNumberOfElements
     *            defines the maximum number of elements the filter is expected to contain.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
     */
    public BloomFilter(int bitSetSize, int expectedNumberOfElements) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        bitSet = new BitSet(bitSetSize);
        /*
         * The natural logarithm is the logarithm to the base e, where e is an irrational and 
         * transcendental constant approximately equal to 2.718281828. 
         */
        hashFunctionCount =  (int) Math.round((bitSetSize / (double)expectedNumberOfElements) * Math.log(2.0));
        md5Digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    }


    /**
     * Generates digests based on the contents of an array of bytes and splits the result into 4-byte int's and store them in an array. The
     * digest function is called until the required number of int's are produced. For each call to digest a salt
     * is prepended to the data. The salt is increased by 1 for each call.
     *
     * @param data specifies input data.
     * @param hashes number of hashes/int's to produce.
     * @return array of int-sized hashes
     */
    private int[] createHashes(byte[] data) {
        int[] result = new int[hashFunctionCount];

        int k = 0;
        byte salt = 0;
        while (k < hashFunctionCount) {
            byte[] digest;
            synchronized (md5Digest) {
                md5Digest.update(salt);
                salt++;
                digest = md5Digest.digest(data);                
            }

            /*
             *  we divide an array into blocks of 4 for example:
             *  - 100 length digest array is broken into pieces of 25 
             *  
             *  But i advances by 4, not by 25.
             */
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length/4 && k < hashFunctionCount; i++) {
                int h = 0;
                // 4 bits are consumed for a single hash.
                for (int j = (i*4); j < (i*4)+4; j++) {
                    h <<= 8;
                    h |= ((int) digest[j]) & 0xFF;
                }
                result[k] = h;
                k++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int getBitIndex(int hash) {
        return Math.abs(hash % bitSet.size());
    }

    /**
     * Adds all elements from a Collection to the Bloom filter.
     * @param c Collection of elements.
     */
    public void addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        for (E element : c)
            add(element);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an object to the Bloom filter. The output from the object's
     * toString() method is used as input to the hash functions.
     *
     * @param element is an element to register in the Bloom filter.
     */
    public void add(E element) {
       add(element.toString().getBytes());
    }

    private void add(byte[] bytes) {
       int[] hashes = createHashes(bytes);
       for (int hash : hashes)
           bitSet.set(getBitIndex(hash), true);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if all the elements of a Collection could have been inserted
     * into the Bloom filter. 
     * @param c elements to check.
     * @return true if all the elements in c could have been inserted into the Bloom filter.
     */
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        for (E element : c)
            if (!contains(element))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the array of bytes could have been inserted into the Bloom filter.
     *
     * @param bytes array of bytes to check.
     * @return true if the array could have been inserted into the Bloom filter.
     */
    public boolean contains(E element) {
        return contains(element.toString().getBytes());
    }


    private boolean contains(byte[] bytes) {
        for (int hash : createHashes(bytes)) {
            if (!bitSet.get(getBitIndex(hash))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sets all bits to false in the Bloom filter.
     */
    public void clear() {
        bitSet.clear();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        BloomFilter<String> bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(10, 2);
        bloomFilter.add("sachin");
        bloomFilter.add("tendulkar");

        System.out.println(bloomFilter.contains("sachin"));
        System.out.println(bloomFilter.contains("tendulkar"));

        System.out.println(bloomFilter.contains("rahul"));
        System.out.println(bloomFilter.contains("dravid"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a comment telling us what `e` is, why not indicate why it is important? Why are setting it to `(int) Math.round((bitSetSize / (double)expectedNumberOfElements) * Math.log(2.0));` and not to `(int)Math.sqrt(bitSetSize * bitSetSize + expectedNumberOfElements * expectedNumberOfElements)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Where's the class-level documentation?
2. ```
   private final MessageDigest md5Digest;
   ```

   will need renaming if you change your hash function. Better to call it `hasher`?
3. ```
    * Constructs an empty Bloom filter. The optimal number of hash functions (k) is estimated from the total size of
    * the Bloom and the number of expected elements.
   ```

   Great, but would it be useful to  have a function to estimate an optimal filter size?
4. ```
        * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
   ```

   isn't very useful. You could say under what conditions it will throw that exception, but basically the conditions come down to "the JRE violates the spec, which says that MD5 will be supported", so it would be more sensible to catch the `NoSuchAlgorithmException` and rethrow it wrapped in a `RuntimeException`. Then just include a unit test to make sure you haven't typoed `"MD5"`.
5. ```
       /*
        * The natural logarithm is the logarithm to the base e, where e is an irrational and 
        * transcendental constant approximately equal to 2.718281828. 
        */
   ```

   As rolfl commented, this is a useless comment. Logarithms and `e` are far more basic concepts than Bloom filters, but you haven't tried to define Bloom filters anywhere. A useful comment here would be a literature reference to justify the estimate.
6. ```
    * Generates digests based on the contents of an array of bytes and splits the result into 4-byte int's and store them in an array. The
    * digest function is called until the required number of int's are produced. For each call to digest a salt
    * is prepended to the data. The salt is increased by 1 for each call.
   ```

   seems like a lot of implementation detail for the javadoc. I would be inclined to inline `getBitIndex` into this method, rename it `getBuckets`, and simplify the javadoc to something like

   ```
    * Hashes the data to generate a set of filter buckets.
   ```

   (on the assumption that the use of buckets is documented at the class level, either directly or via literature reference).
7. ```
    * @param hashes number of hashes/int's to produce.
   ```

   doesn't seem to correspond to a parameter of the method.
8. ```
            *  we divide an array into blocks of 4 for example:
            *  - 100 length digest array is broken into pieces of 25 
            *  
            *  But i advances by 4, not by 25.
   ```

   confused me. I had to read the code to understand the comment, which rather defeats the purpose. *Why* are you splitting it?

   ```
            * The MessageDigest output has far more entropy than we need, so
            * we break it into 4-byte chunks and use each chunk to compute a
            * bucket index.
   ```
9. ```
               int h = 0;
               // 4 bits are consumed for a single hash.
               for (int j = (i*4); j < (i*4)+4; j++) {
                   h <<= 8;
                   h |= ((int) digest[j]) & 0xFF;
               }
   ```

   is something which could be pulled out into a general-purpose bit bashing library, as a function `toIntBigEndian(byte[] buf, int off)`. Also, that cast is unnecessary: `byte`s and `short`s are automatically promoted to `int` by any arithmetic or bitwise operation.
10. ```
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length/4 && k < hashFunctionCount; i++) {
    ```

    seems more complicated to me than

    ```
            for (int i = 0; i + 3 < digest.length && k < hashFunctionCount; i += 4) {
    ```

    and frankly you can safely use

    ```
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length && k < hashFunctionCount; i += 4) {
    ```

    because there's no widely used MessageDigest whose output isn't a multiple of 32 bits.
11. ```
     * Adds an object to the Bloom filter. The output from the object's
     * toString() method is used as input to the hash functions.
    ```

    Two things: firstly, the fact that it uses the object's `toString()` as its identity is something that should be mentioned at the class level. Secondly, it strikes me as a bad idea anyway. If you're only working with strings, make that explicit by taking strings instead of genericising the class. Alternatively, add a field for a "serialiser" object which converts `E` to `byte[]`, with the default being one that works via `toString()`.
12. ```
    element.toString().getBytes()
    ```

    is a bit suspect. You could get different results with the same test case on different machines, or even on the same machine in different locales.